# How do you push changes to GitHub on OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, github

I'm really new to the whole GitHub thing so this might seem like a basic question but I can't figure it out.

I have a GitHub repository set up on my machine, I've managed at some point to push the master but now I have made some changes and I want to push the entire thing again (pretty much everything changed).

What I'm wondering is:

1. How do you push an entire repository to create a new version (from version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1)?
2. How do you push a single file for more incremental changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use git on OS X, make sure to check:

- [the official version of gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/)
- [the experimental version of Brotherboard:](http://brotherbard.com/blog/2010/03/experimental-gitx-fork/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [brotherbard.com](http://brotherbard.com/gitx/gitx_screenshot_2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can't push a single file with git, you always push at least a complete branch. The command is `git push`, and if you've made changes that alter history already present in the remote repository you might need to add `--force`. You can look at the guide at [github](http://github.com/guides/push-a-branch-to-github) for a pointer, or [the manual page for git push](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for a complete description.

Answer (score 1):

First you must use the commit command. Even if you change a single file you must execute commit. After committing you can use the push command.